# Transfer Items to and from users Using AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Ok, so I'm working with AngularJS and Firebase and trying to create a simple exchange between two users.  Right now my data structure is set up under "users/uId/" and then their email, date they joined, and gold.

Under gold (users/uId/gold) I have "sent" which captures the amount, time and to whom (email).  This is the code snippet below.  It also updates their total gold.

Now I'm stuck updating the person they're sending the gold to. I capture the email address, but everything under scope relates to the current logged in user.  How would I update the new users users/uId/gold/received with the amount, time and email who it was from, along with updating their total gold?

I feel like I might be going about this the wrong way, any help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
ledger.controller('TransferController', function (
$scope, $firebase, $routeParams, $location, $rootScope, FIREBASE_URL) {

    $scope.whichuser = $routeParams.uId;
    $scope.goldsends = goldsendList;

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + $scope.whichuser + '/gold/' + '/sent/');
    var hopperRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + '/users/' + $scope.whichuser + '/gold/');
    var usersRef = ref.child("users");
    var goldsendList = $firebase(ref).$asArray();


    $scope.sendGold = function () {
        var sendgoldObj = $firebase(ref); //this var has to match the sendgoldObj.$push var down below, and that's it

        var myData = {
            amount: $scope.user.amount,
            email: $scope.user.email,
            date: Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        };

        sendgoldObj.$push(myData).then(function () {
            //   $location.path('/myledger/');  //page redirect
        }); //data sent to firebase.

        if ($scope.currentUser.gold.total - Math.abs($scope.user.amount) > 0) { //

            var hopperRefff = hopperRef.child("gold");
            hopperRef.update({
                "total": $scope.currentUser.gold.total - $scope.user.amount
            }); //update total gold

            var receive = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
            ref.child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(emailAddress).once('value', function (snap) {
                console.log(snap.name() + (snap.val() === null ? ' DOES NOT' : ' does') + ' exist');
            }); //trying to find user to send gold to

        } //if user has enough gold statement
        else {
            return {
                scope: {
                    errormessage: 'You don\'t have enough money',
                }
            };
            console.log("not enough money!");
        } //else note enough gold statement

    } //sendgold
}); //TransferController
```

Comment: You have the right approach with `ref.child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(emailAddress)`. So what is the problem with that code fragment?

Comment: That code works for telling me if the email exists in the database, but then how do I push data to that user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a value to the user is just a variation of checking if that user exists. Once you have a snapshot, you can get back to a ref by calling `ref`

```
ref.child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(emailAddress).once('value', function (snap) {        
    snap.ref().update({ "total": snap.val().total + amount });
});
```

Not that this is just a sample, so you'll probably have to update it for your actual data structure.

### Update

The above will get you the value of the `users` node.

You either need to capture the `once('child_added'` or `forEach` over the `on('value'`. I'll give an example of both.

Listening to `child_added`:

```
ref.child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(emailAddress).once('child_added', function (snap) {        
    snap.ref().update({ "total": snap.val().total + amount });

});
```

An example of looping over the `value`:

```
ref.child('users').orderByChild('email').equalTo(emailAddress).once('value', function (snap) {        
    snap.forEach(function(childsnap) {
        childsnap.ref().update({ "total": snap.val().total + amount });

});
```

Here's a jsbin with both samples: http://jsbin.com/fenavu/1/edit?js,console. Note that the code here writes out the `ref.toString()`, which gives you the full URL of the node (since every piece of data in Firebase has its own unique URL). That can be a handy way to figure out what URL your node maps to.

Comment: Hey Frank! Thanks, that's on the right track, but that's not snapping to where the email is, it's just adding "gold: total" to the base "users", rather than to that specific user.  Am I missing something to make sure it updates under that user, rather than just "Users" in general?

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that. You should probably use `once('child_added'` to get into the child. But since you obviously think that email addresses are a good way to identify users, why don't you just use the email address as the name of the user's node too? That would bring the line back to a more manageable `ref.child('users').child(emailAddress).update(...`.

Comment: Hey Frank!  just by switching 'value' to 'child_added' worked perfect! (your first example).  Thanks a TON!  I think if I just used the email as the user's node, I'd still have the same problem, because I'd need to update under the current user, as well as a different user.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't see how this answer solves the problem. Surely you don't want to give users write permission to set the total etc. on another user's account? See my answer below for using an observed request-based approach. You can handle any type of request then in a Node script and make the respective changes as admin to whichever user is targeted.

Comment: The question was not "how to securely transfer money between player?", but "why can't my code find the other user?", so that is what I answered. If you care about security, this is a better solution that doesn't require hosting your own server: https://github.com/tomlarkworthy/firesafe/wiki/Send-Item

Answer (score 1):

You could store the users by email where the `@` is replaced by `_` and a `.` is replaced with `-`

So you have a JSON structure like this in Firebase

```
users: {
   "bob_hoskins-com": { 
      email: "bob@hoskins.com",
      date: "09-09-1999",
      gold: {
          ...
      }
   }
}
```

However, I don't think this is a great approach for this problem.

I would create a node service that is observing a `requests` Firebase location on each user for added children. The node service will then do the calculations and write the data to the correct paths, then can delete the request once processed.

So you would have rules on your Firebase like this

```
{
  "rules": {
    "$userId": {
      "requests": {
        ".read": "auth != null && $userId == auth.id",          
        ".write": "auth != null && $userId == auth.id"          
      },
      "responses": {
        ".read": "auth != null && $userId == auth.id",
        ".write": "auth != null && $userId == auth.id"          
      }
   }
}
```

Here is some request code

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');

function s4() {
  return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
             .toString(16)
             .substring(1);
}

function guid() {
  return s4() + s4() + s4() + s4();
}

var _ref = new Firebase('https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/');

//Log me in
var guid = guid();
var FirebaseTokenGenerator = require("firebase-token-generator");
var tokenGenerator = new FirebaseTokenGenerator("YOUR_TOKEN");
var TOKEN = tokenGenerator.createToken({uid: guid, user: "node server"},{admin: true});

_ref.authWithCustomToken(TOKEN, function (error) {
  if(error) {
    console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
    console.log("Login Succeeded!", guid);
  }
});

_ref.on('child_added', function (user) {
    var requests = user.ref().child('requests');
    requests.on('child_added', function(req) {
        handleRequest(req);
    });
});

var handleRequest = function (request) {
   // Process the request
   // Write stuff back to Firebase

   // Delete the request
   request.ref().remove();
};
```