# Pushing Data To A Child Node with AngularJS and Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm getting this:

```
"users" : {
    "simplelogin:129" : {
      "-JbX-CJuMDf1H8-yCETV" : {
        "gold" : {
          "receive" : {
            "amount" : 1,
            "date" : 1416835946409,
            "email" : "you@me.com"
          }
        }
      },
```

But I need something like this:

```
"users" : {
    "simplelogin:130" : {
    "date" : 1416834728422,
    "email" : "yam@dam.com",
    "id" : "130",
    "gold" : {
       "receive" : {
         "-JbWva7Gh9Y3RarlF77h" : {
             "amount" : 1,
             "date" : 1416834737201,
             "email" : "you@do.com"
      },
```

If I use .update instead of .push, I get the file structure I need, but then it overrides it for each transaction instead of adding a new one each time.

```
receive.orderByChild("email").equalTo( $scope.user.email ).once('child_added', function(snap) {
        snap.ref().push({gold: {receive: myGold}}).then(function() {
});
```

Comment: Calling `push` generates a new node for you with a unique ID. If will do so every time, so you're cannot be overwriting the previous transfer when you push a new one. Please include the minimal code to show your problem and clearly show the result you got and the result you were expecting (preferably both as real JSON structures, instead of textual descriptions of them). It also might be worthwhile to set up a jsfiddle/jsbin/plunkr showing the problem.

Comment: Added pictures to hopefully make the predicament more clear :) I need a new node under "gold: receive", rather than a new node just under where it snaps to.

Comment: No pictures please, just code and data (which are searchable and copy/paste-able when someones tries to reproduce your problem). Now I am going to have to type it up in my answer, time I could've spent helping someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but I assume that you want to push the new node deeper in the tree.

```
simplelogin:130
  date: ...
  email: "yam@dam.com"
  id: 130
  gold
    received
      -JbX-CJuMDf1H8-yCETV
        amount: 1
        date: ...
        email: "yam@dam.com"
```

To put the data into gold/received, you'd do:

```
snap.ref().child('gold/receive').push(myGold);
```

So you **first** find the node you want to add something to and only then call `push` to add a new child (with a new unique id) there.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I wanted to do, sorry my explanation was so terrible!  I couldn't find any documentation on how to add data to a child node! I was trying to add it different ways, but that was spot on.  THANKS!!!

Comment: Please take a moment to update your question and include the data structures instead of those screenshots.

Comment: Tried my best, hopefully that's a little more descriptive now!

Comment: Yup. Better. Note that @stukennedy's remarks in his answer to your previous question still stand: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27096041/209103. Giving everyone "blind" access to everyone else's data is not very secure and you might want to consider a different approach, either with a server-side mode (as Stu suggested) or by writing more complex security rules (as documented here: https://github.com/tomlarkworthy/firesafe/wiki/Send-Item)